# Connect byobu from Mac El Capitan, Shift + F3 and Shift + F4 do not work

Tags: byobu

I use my Mac to connect to a remote Ubuntu server (Trusty 14.04) running byobu. Everthing works fine when I connect from the local Ubuntu installed on the Mac as a dual-boot OS. However when I connect from Mac El Captinan, the key combination for jumping to different splits of the same window do not work. F3 and F4 work because I can jump forward and backward to other tabbed window.

What's would be the fix for this?

Comment: This seems a question fo [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/). However, please try `fn`+`Shift`+`F3` and `fn`+`Shift`+`F4` and let me know if then behaves correctly.

Comment: @Helio  It's something mainly with `bybobu`. So I think it is better be here. I haven't used the Mac OS since then so I haven't check your suggestion.